# How to build Assimp library in 32-bit for C++?

Tags: c++, build, compilation, assimp

I am trying to build Assimp as a 32-bit library so I can load models with it. However, I have tried generating solutions with every version of Assimp with CMake and it only gives me a x64 option. How do I compile any version of Assimp for 32-bit as in x86?

There are prebuilt binaries online that don't work so I want to try building it myself but can't since there's no 32-bit option.

Comment: Do you use VS2019?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build on Windows with Visual-Studio 2019 the 32bit mode was removed. For this scenario, you can use a mingw-build. It is possible to generate the makefiles by using cmake. Or you can just switch to VS2017.

On other platforms using 32-bit shall be possible if the compiler does support this kind of build.